# Update with a prepared statement and bind row with an id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My database consist of the following columns: `id, openingHours, records`.

I have a HTML table where I get printed out rows from the MySQL database. To the right of each HTML row I have a button where I can click Select. When I click Select I need to update the column `records` with +1 with the belonging column `id`.

That query is working in phpMyAdmin if I use the query like this:

```
sqli = ("UPDATE stores SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = 333);
```

But I need to bind the id on the row where I use the select button. When I click the select button with this code, the row in phpMyAdmin is not getting updated. What am I doing wrong? I get the error: `Undefined index: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/storeproject/updaterecords.php on line 8 Updated Succesfull.`

**HTML**

```
<form action="updaterecords.php" method="post">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Select</button>
   <?php include 'updaterecords.php' ?>
</form>
```

**updaterecords.php**

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error: no connexion allowed : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); } 
?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$id = $_POST['id']; //line 8

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stores SET records = records + 1 WHERE id =".$id);

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);   

    if ($stmt->execute()) { 
        $success = true;
    }

    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();   
    if($success) {
        echo "Updated Succesfull";
    } else {
        echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
      }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes

`$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stores SET records = records + 1 WHERE 
  id= ?");`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I tried with your code and at least I am getting an error now: `Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/storeproject/updaterecords.php on line 8
Updated Succesfull`. That is on the line `$id = $_POST['id'];`. As I see it the id should not be undefined, when I am defining the id there?

Comment: It seems you are not getting the id parameter from the client side. Thats the only i can think of.